# Undefined control sequence when trying to insert math inside enumerate

Tags: equations, enumerate

I'm trying to insert some math inside enumeration like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Pagal (\ref{10}) ir (\ref{11}) įrodome tankio santykinės paklaidos $\left( \delta \rho = \fraction {\Delta \rho} {\rho} \right)$ formules

    \begin{equation}
      \delta {\rho}_{1} = \pm \left( \frac {\Delta m} {m} + \frac {\Delta l} {l} + \frac {2 \Delta d} {d}\right) \labe{eq:12}
    \end{equation}

    ir

    \begin{equation}
      \delta {\rho}_{2} = \pm \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\Delta m} {m} \right)^2 + \left( \frac {\Delta l} {l} \right)^2 + \left( \frac {2 \Delta d} {d} \right)^2} \labe{eq:13}
    \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.108 ...paklaidos $\left( \delta \rho = \fraction
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: It should be `\frac` not `\fraction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to add fraction in LaTeX is `\frac`. Also you should use `\label` and not `\labe`. With these corrections your code does compile. Also you shouldn't use just numeric labels but try to give them some meaning.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Pagal (\ref{10}) ir (\ref{11}) įrodome tankio santykinės paklaidos
      $\left( \delta \rho = \frac {\Delta \rho} {\rho} \right)$ formules
    \begin{equation}
      \delta {\rho}_{1} = \pm \left( \frac {\Delta m} {m} + \frac {\Delta l} {l}
      + \frac {2 \Delta d} {d}\right) \label{eq:12}
    \end{equation}
    ir
    \begin{equation}
      \delta {\rho}_{2} = \pm \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\Delta m} {m} \right)^2 +
      \left( \frac {\Delta l} {l} \right)^2 + \left( \frac {2 \Delta d} {d}
  \right)^2} \label{eq:13}
    \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Comment: Ahh, my eyes are melting and I can't spot typos. After these edits I get anothererror: `LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 103 ended by \end{enumrate}.`

Comment: @PoVa I've spotted another typo (`|Delta` instead of `\Delta`)

Comment: @PoVa In the new error you commented the `\end{enumerate}` is missing an `e`.

Comment: There should be no blank lines around the `equation` environments, in this case. As a general rule, a blank line should never precede `equation`; one can follow, if the text below the equation starts a new paragraph.

Comment: @egreg yes you're right. I did only correct the errors to make it compilable. But for styling (and semantic) rules there should be no empty lines. I'll edit my answer.